# Mathematical Proof (Apostol)

Tags: calculus, analysis, inequality

If $x > 0$, prove that there is a positive integer $n$ such that $\frac{1}{n} < x$ byy either contradiction or contrapositives.

### My attempts

**By contrapositives:**
**Givens by contrapositive method**
$n > 0$
$n$ is an integer
$\frac{1}{n} > x$

**Prove by contrapositive method**
$x < 0$

**Proof**
$n > 0$
and $x$ is an arbitrary real number
There is a real positive integer $y$ such that

$ny > x$ [Archimedean Property]

$x < ny$

But I cant go any further.

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The given statement states $x \in \Bbb R^{+}\implies (\exists n \in \Bbb N , \frac {1}{n}\lt x)$. The contrapositive of this statement would be $\neg(\exists n \in \Bbb N , \frac {1}{n}\lt x)\implies \neg (x \in \Bbb R^{+})$, i.e., $(\forall n \in \Bbb N\frac {1}{n}\geq x) \implies x \leq 0$, provided the universe of discourse is the set of real numbers. You cannot fix the positive integer $n$ like that.

Proof by contradiction would be to observe that $(\forall n \in \Bbb N\frac {1}{n}\geq x) \implies (\forall n \in \Bbb N\frac {1}{n}\cdot n\geq x\cdot n)$ (since $(\forall n \in \Bbb N,\space n\gt 0))$ which means $(\forall n \in \Bbb N\frac {1}{n}\geq x)\implies (\forall n \in \Bbb N,1\geq nx)$. Now, if $x \gt 0$, this would be in conflict with the Archimedian property. Hence we must have $x \leq 0$.